# Convert JAVA program to PHP code

Tags: java, php

I have below program in JAVA.

```
private static int frogJump(int[] arrEl,int postion) {
        /** Marker array for the leaf found on the way. */
        boolean[] leafArray = new boolean[postion+1];

        /** Total step needed for frog. */
        int steps = postion;

        for(int i = 0; i<arrEl.length; i++) {

            /** if leaf needed for frog and it does not exist earlier. **/
            if(postion>=arrEl[i] && !leafArray[arrEl[i]]) {

                /* Mark leaf found */
                leafArray[arrEl[i]] = true;

                /** Reduce the step by one(coz one jump found). */
                steps--;
            }

            if(steps == 0 && arrEl[i]==postion) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Which i want to convert in PHP.
Till now what i have done is

```
function solution ($A = [], $Position) {

    $StonesArray = array();

    $StonesArray[TRUE] = $Position + 1;

    $steps = $Position;

    for($i = 0; $i< count($A); $i++) {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($StonesArray);

        if($Position >= $A[$i] && !$StonesArray[$A[$i]]) {


            $StonesArray[$A[$i]] = true;


            $steps--;
        }

        if($steps == 0 && $A[$i] == $Position) {
            return $i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

$GetSolution  = solution([3,2,1], 1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($GetSolution);
```

above program should return 3. but after i have converted the program to PHP language its not returning the expected value.

I am sure I have done everything correct except converting the below line

```
boolean[] leafArray = new boolean[postion+1];
```

How to write this line in PHP?

Comment: **This is not C**. I can't tell for sure what it is (C#? C++?) Please determine yourself and correct the tag.

Comment: Check the code on http://www.codesolution.org/frog-jump-through-leaves-problem/

Comment: Looking into the source code says it highlights for **java** (It has the class `syntaxhighlighter  java`)

Comment: I think that's C#, anyway I don't think you can create an array with predefined size in PHP. And usually you don't need to. Just use `$leafArray = array();`

Comment: let me edit my Question then,,

Comment: you just need to store boolean values in your `$StoneArray`, that's all. `boolean[] leafArray = new boolean[postion+1]` means an array of size `position+1` and contains booleans.

Comment: @xander , are you sure ? instead of `boolean[] leafArray = new boolean[postion+1];`  just `$leafArray = array(); will work` ? ? , because they have added some values , please check.

Comment: Yes, it should work @Jhon. `$leafArray = array()` will create an array that will expand as needed, but the original Java version _reserved_ `postion+1` spaces for this array. In PHP you do not need to do that.

Comment: @Metaphox , thanks for understanding, but i am learning php myself, so can you please tell me how do i define this array of size position+1 and contains booleans ?

Comment: i cant understand  how `boolean[] leafArray = new boolean[postion+1];` will become  only `$leafArray = array();` in php, we  can clearly see they have assigned some values. or given the size of an array

Comment: Well if that code is Java then `new boolean[postion+1];` will create an bool array of size `postion+1` and set all element to false initially. if you want to achieve the same in php you can only use `$leafArray = array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);`

Comment: @xander , @ MetaPhox ,  still not getting the expected output..  let me know if i have converted the program correctly..   i am editing the entire question ,

Comment: `$StonesArray[TRUE] = $Position + 1;` makes no sense, you really just need to have an array and put `$Position + 1` times `false`s into it.

Comment: @Metaphox , that is what i dont understand .   how can i write it. ?

Comment: Did you see my comment, I edited it a few times sorry... `array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);` that creates an array with all values set to false and should match the Java array.

Comment: @xander , i tried this . but still not getting the answer what i want. something is really wrong  we need to figure out.  do i need to assign this line `array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);` to $leafArray ? like  `$leafarray = array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);`  like this  ??

Comment: Well yes the array you are using, it's called `leafArray` in the original code but you called it `$StonesArray` so it should be `$StonesArray = array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);` (would be easier to compare if not all variables had diifferent names in your codes) :)

Comment: @xander yes i wrote `$StonesArray = array_fill(0, $position + 1, false);` but still not getting the output i want.  anyways,. thank for your time.. 
but last time can you please check if i have converted the php code correctly ?

Comment: That line looks ok now, in general you should do a step by step comparision or debug your code to see where the difference is to the original code. If you update your question with your current code I'll take a look, but this is not a chat a moderator might move this conversation to a chat channel if we continue to discuss it in the comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just translated your original Java code to PHP 1:1, most of it can be used as is with little change, look at this example:

```
function frogJump(array $arrEl, $postion) {
    /** Marker array for the leaf found on the way. */
    $leafArray = array_fill(0, $postion+1, false);

    /** Total step needed for frog. */
    $steps = $postion;

    for($i = 0; $i<count($arrEl); $i++) {

        /** if leaf needed for frog and it does not exist earlier. **/
        if($postion>=$arrEl[$i] && !$leafArray[$arrEl[$i]]) {

            /* Mark leaf found */
            $leafArray[$arrEl[$i]] = true;

            /** Reduce the step by one(coz one jump found). */
            $steps--;
        }

        if($steps == 0 && $arrEl[$i]==$postion) {
            return $i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

`print_r(frogJump([3,2,1], 1));` outputs `2`.

I also compiled the Java code and the output is also `2`, so it seems correct to me? Run with `System.out.println(frogJump(new int[]{3,2,1}, 1));`

Comment: I have not enough rep. to access chat.

Comment: I think if my answer solves your problem you can just accept it and the question is closed. If you have further questions just ask here in the comments or create a new question.